# How to prove basics calculations in fields

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning about fields in Linear Algebra and I still dont get how to prove things in fields, for example
1. F∈a.F∈a.
and I need to prove that if a^2 = 1 , then a = 1 or a= -1
2. if a^2 =a , then a =0 or a = 1

This what I did :
1. a^2 =1 --> a^2 -1 = 0 --> a^2 -1 *1=0 (1 is neutral -axiom)--> 
a^2 -1^2 --> (a+1)(a-1) = 0 --> a=1 or a=-1 .

2. a^2 - a = 0 --> a*(a-1) = 0 --> a=0 or a= 1.

is that good or should I use more fields axioms ?

Comment: That's difficult to answer without more context. If you have just learnt the Field axioms and the exercises are meant to test you on that then you are probably expected to justify all inferences by explicitly naming the axioms, lemmas, etc that you employ. Look st the worked examples to get an idea of how much detail is expected in such proofs.

Comment: Yea, I just started to learn fields and the problem is I dont now how to use other axioms to prove it, I mean it seems pretty obvious